# How to write a wrapper for AreaRegistration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a wrapper for AreaRegistration to constrain certain patterns for different areas. My Code looks like below:

```
public abstract class WrappedAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public abstract override string AreaName
    {
        get;
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        var uri = string.Format("Wrapper/{0}/{{controller}}", AreaName);

        context.MapRoute(
            string.Format("{0}_default", AreaName),
            uri,
            new { action = "Index" });
    }
}
```

In my area A, there is a class called

```
public class A : WrappedAreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName{
        get{
            return "A";
        }
}
```

And I have an area B with almost the same code above.

```
public class B : WrappedAreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName{
        get{
            return "B";
        }
}
```

The outcome of runtime is: area A can be routed successfully but area B hit a 404 error. However, when I do the traditional way, which is not using a wrapper, direct using class A and class B to inherit AreaRegistration abstract class, I don't have this issue, A and B can be successfully routed.

I installed a tool called glimpse.MVC4 to check the route configuration at run time, the namespaces for both area A and area B are "A" and "B".

Comment: You wrote 'area B with almost the same code'. Almost != the same. Can you provide code of `B` class?

Comment: Wild guess but MVC might be using the namespace of the area registration class to figure out what area it applies to. What are the namespaces you are using and where are they in your file structure?

Comment: I have updated the article above.